# Percentage of Total with Groupby for two columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby

I have a DataFrame:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'Product': ['AA', 'AA', 'AA', 'AA', 'BB', 'BB', 'BB', 'BB'],
    'Type': ['AC', 'AC', 'AD', 'AD', 'BC', 'BC', 'BD', 'BD'],
    'Sales': [ 200, 100, 400, 100, 300, 100, 200, 500], 
    'Qty': [ 5, 3, 3, 6, 4, 7, 4, 1]})
```

I want to try and get the percentage of total by "Product" and "Type" for both "Sales" and "Qty". I can get the percentage of total for "Sales" and "Qty" separately. But I was wondering if there was a way of doing so for both columns.

To get the percentage of total for one column, the code is:

```
df['Sales'] = df['Sales'].astype(float)
df['Qty'] = df['Qty'].astype(float)
df = df[['Product', 'Type', 'Sales']]

df = df.groupby(['Product', 'Type']).agg({'Sales': 'sum'})
pcts = df.groupby(level= [0]).apply(lambda x: 100 * x / float(x.sum()))
```

Is there a way of get this for both columns in one go?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can chain `groupby`:

```
pct = lambda x: 100 * x / x.sum()

out = df.groupby(['Product', 'Type']).sum().groupby('Product').apply(pct)
print(out)

# Output
                  Sales        Qty
Product Type                      
AA      AC    37.500000  47.058824
        AD    62.500000  52.941176
BB      BC    36.363636  68.750000
        BD    63.636364  31.250000
```

Comment: This is nice, but I'd _really_ avoid the groupby.apply in favor of the additional groupby with cythonized functions. The apply will turn a trivial math calculation into something that takes way to long for many groups

Comment: @ALollz. Do you mean https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/enhancingperf.html#cython-writing-c-extensions-for-pandas?

Comment: I just meant that groupby.apply is general so it defaults to a python loop over the groups. Things like `DataFrame.GroupBy.sum` are optimized so they are much more performant with many groups. So though the `.apply` winds up being very nice and clean from a syntax perspective the performance can suffer a ton compared do something like @enke's solution where it's more steps but uses two optimized calculations.

Answer (score 3):

You could `groupby` "Product" and "Type" get the totals for each group. Then `groupby` "Product" (which is level=0) again and transform `sum`; then divide the sum from the previous step with it:

```
sm = df.groupby(['Product','Type']).sum()
out = sm / sm.groupby(level=0).transform('sum') * 100
```

Output:

```
                  Sales        Qty
Product Type                      
AA      AC    37.500000  47.058824
        AD    62.500000  52.941176
BB      BC    36.363636  68.750000
        BD    63.636364  31.250000
```

Answer (score 2):

One option is to get the values from individual groupbys and divide:

```py
numerator = df.groupby(["Product", "Type"]).sum()
denominator = df.groupby("Product").sum()
numerator.div(denominator, level = 0, axis = 'index') * 100

                  Sales        Qty
Product Type                      
AA      AC    37.500000  47.058824
        AD    62.500000  52.941176
BB      BC    36.363636  68.750000
        BD    63.636364  31.250000
```